# How to insert a python list into Postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to determine the simplest way to insert data from a python list into a PostgreSQL table.

My PostgreSQL table was created as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE results(Id serial primary key, T0 timestamp, T1 real, T2 real, T3 real, T4 real, Total real, Result text);
```

My python list is formatted as follows;

```
ResultsList = ['2015-07-20 16:06:05', 0.16, 5.22, 5.81, 0.69, 11.90, 'OK']
```

I am using the following python code to write the list into the results table;

```
import psycopg2 as dbapi
con = dbapi.connect(database='xxx', user='xxx')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT into results VALUES (%s);", (ResultsList),)
con.commit()
```

The interpreter spits out the following error;

```
Error not all arguments converted during string formatting
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any clues would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Pretty sure there's a python syntax error there, with that trailing comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `ResultList` is already a sequence, you do not need to try and convert it to a tuple. What you really need is specify the right amount of values in your SQL statement:

```
cur.execute("INSERT into results(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, Total, Result) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", ResultList)
```

For more about it, read [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters).

Comment: This won't work. You would need to specify the column names otherwise it would start from the id column.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone We need that because not all of them are specified, right? Otherwise we could omit them.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes. If you do not specify column names it would start inserting from the id column (so it will consider all the columns of the table including the id). In some DBMS (like MySQL) you can do that by specifying the first element as NULL (and the ID with autoincrement will be autogenerated) but I'm not sure about Postgresql.

Answer (score -1):

LOADING MULTIPLE VALUES FROM A LIST INTO A POSTGRESQL TABLE.
I have also shown how to connect to a postgres database through python and create a table in postgres.

```
list_1=[39,40,41,42,43] #list to load in postgresql table


conn=psycopg2.connect(database="t2_reporting_tool_development",user="xyz",host="localhost")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("create table pg_table (col1 int)")

#LOADING dealers_list IN pg_table TABLE 
cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE pg_table")
for ddeci in dealers_list:
   cur.execute("INSERT into pg_table(col1) VALUES (%s)", [ddeci])
```