# Insert python list into PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on a scraping project and I'm struggling with inserting data into database.

My database has three columns: id, post and author
Scraped data is stored in two lists. First one is list posts and second one is authors. Both are the same length always because there are no articles without content or articles without author.

I've tried solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510945/how-to-insert-a-python-list-into-postgres-table) question but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scrape.py", line 69, in <module>
cur.execute("INSERT into posts(id, post, author) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", authors)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My lists look like this:

```
author = [n1, n2, n3 ... n45]
posts = [n1, n2, n3 ... n45]
```

And I would like to insert them into database like this:

```
ID | Post | Author
---|------|--------
1  | Text | Author
2  | Text | Author
```

Later on I would need to extract stats from values in post column. To be exact word and number of how many times they appear but I guess it qualifies for another question.

Comment: You have 45 values in your list and only 3 strings to format

Comment: @cricket_007 so I guess I've made mistake ealier, I should push the data when scraping it so I would add row by row, am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You tried to insert a list of authors into a table of posts ? That doesn't quite make sense.

Surely you're looking for something like this

```
data = [(1, 'post', 'author'), (2, 'post', 'author')]
for d in data:
    cur.execute("INSERT into posts(id, post, author) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", d)
```

Also id values are typically integers, but you seem to be formatting as a string

If you want to keep individual lists, check out the result of `zip(posts, authors)`

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day! I was trying so hard that I haven't thought I made mistake way ealier in my code.